# .getContent() method generation issue in Jaxb class

Tags: jaxb

i am having issue while regenerating the JAXB classes.my previous xsd  generated the below method automatically through JAXB class generation .

```
public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }
```

But my new XSD did not.

```
<xsd:element name="AppInfo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="AppInfo_Type"/>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="AppInfo_Type">
<xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="b" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="ID"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

What will drive this method generation in XSD?

Comment: What are the JAXB annotations on the corresponding `content` field, and what does the complex type look like that corresponds to the class that has the `content` property?

Comment: My XSd luks as below ....But iam not able idetify what is driving this .getContent() method genration from XSD? <xsd:element name="AppInfo"> <xsd:complexType> <xsd:complexContent> <xsd:extension base="AppInfo_Type"/> </xsd:complexContent> </xsd:complexType> </xsd:element> <xsd:complexType name="Appinfo_Type">

Comment: My Xsd looks as below    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
 <xsd:complexType name="Appinfo_Type">

Comment: Can you edit your question where I did to put more of your XML schema.  In particular the complex type called `Appinfo_Type`.

Comment: <xsd:element name="AppInfo">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="AppInfo_Type"/>
   </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
 <xsd:complexType name="AppInfo_Type">
 <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element ref="a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   <xsd:element ref="b" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="id" type="ID"/>
 </xsd:complexType> I have pasted my xsd properly iam not sure what is drving the .get conent method genration .

Comment: Is that your real XML schema or a simplified version?

Comment: never mind i got that resolved on my own .....problem is with xsd if we have any unnamed elements or duplicate element defined in xsd it automatically genrating the .getContent method ....other wise it is not....Blaise Doughan thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 1):

Add a `mixed="true"` attribute to your ComplexType:

```
<xsd:complexType name="AppInfo_Type" mixed="true">
```